# Can you separate programms from D-Bus messages with only one service?

Tags: c++, linux, dbus

e.g. you have three programs P1, P2, P3 and only one service (e.g. "myservice.from.myprogram").
A constellation can be:

Messages between P1 and P2 avoiding P3

Messages between P1 and P3 avoiding P2

Please be so kind to inform if there is no possibility, but if there is one, how can this look like.

Comment: What is the problem?
Add jbr: Downsizing without any notable reason is no correct way!

Answer (score 0):

my learning is based on

[this tutorial](http://madison-project.wdfiles.com/local--files/tutorials/Dbus_Tutorial.pdf)

and

[this thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521661/d-bus-tutorial-in-c-to-communicate-with-wpa-supplicant)

And now I'm wondering if **anyone**, who use the **same** service, can grab messages on that service. Even the arguments can be get by iteration (, as far as I could understood).

Is this behavior wanted? Or is there a way to set specifically access on messages?
(E.g. P3 only can get messages from P1, and P2 too, and naturally P1 from P2 **and** P3.)

TIA and with regards

Earllybite