# D-BUS in BeagleBone Black

Tags: c, linux, debian, dbus, beagleboneblack

**My goal**: Is to monitor the state of my network interface (mainly wireless) from my firmware (in C) by monitoring the wpa_supplicant through the D-Bus interfaces. *I would like to stick with C and low-level API of D-bus.*

## What I have so far

1. I've written a small program in C, copied most of the code as is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521661/d-bus-tutorial-in-c-to-communicate-with-wpa-supplicant?lq=1) SO user.
2. I've gone through all possible tutorials on D-Bus and wpa_supplicant
3. My program compiles and works properly. However it does not produce the expected output.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                  
#include <dbus/dbus.h>

#define WPAS_DBUS_SERVICE   "fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant"
#define WPAS_DBUS_PATH      "/fi/epitest/hostap/WPASupplicant"
#define WPAS_DBUS_INTERFACE "fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicantAAA"

#define WPAS_DBUS_PATH_INTERFACES   WPAS_DBUS_PATH "/Interfaces"
#define WPAS_DBUS_IFACE_INTERFACE   WPAS_DBUS_INTERFACE ".Interfaces"

#define WPAS_DBUS_NETWORKS_PART "Networks"
#define WPAS_DBUS_IFACE_NETWORK WPAS_DBUS_INTERFACE ".Network"

#define WPAS_DBUS_BSSIDS_PART   "BSSIDs"
#define WPAS_DBUS_IFACE_BSSID   WPAS_DBUS_INTERFACE ".BSSID"

int ret;
char signalDesc[1024];     // Signal description as string

// Signal handling
signal(SIGKILL, stopLoop);
signal(SIGTERM, stopLoop);

void loop(DBusConnection* conn)

{
DBusMessage* msg;
DBusMessageIter args;
DBusMessageIter subArgs;
int argType;
int i;
int buffSize = 1024;
char strValue[buffSize];
const char* member = 0;


while (1)
{
// non blocking read of the next available message
dbus_connection_read_write(conn, 0);
msg = dbus_connection_pop_message(conn);

// loop again if we haven't read a message
if (!msg)
{
printf("No message received, waiting a little ...\n");
sleep(1);
continue;
}
else printf("Got a message, will analyze it ...\n");

// Print the message member
printf("Got message for interface %s\n",
dbus_message_get_interface(msg));
member = dbus_message_get_member(msg);
if(member) printf("Got message member %s\n", member);

// Check has argument

if (!dbus_message_iter_init(msg, &args))
{       
printf("Message has no argument\n");
continue;
}
else
{
// Go through arguments
while(1)
{
argType = dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type(&args);

if (argType == DBUS_TYPE_STRING)
{
printf("Got string argument, extracting ...\n");
char* str = NULL;
dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&args, &str);
printf("Received string: \n %s \n",str);

}   
else
printf("Arg type not implemented yet !\n");

if(dbus_message_iter_has_next(&args))
dbus_message_iter_next(&args);
else break;
}   
printf("No more arguments!\n");
}

// free the message
dbus_message_unref(msg);
}       
}           

int main()
{

DBusConnection *connection;

DBusError error;

char *name = "org.share.linux";

dbus_error_init(&error);

connection = dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM, &error);

if ( dbus_error_is_set(&error) )

{

printf("Error connecting to the daemon bus: %s",error.message);

dbus_error_free(&error);

return 1;

}

// request a name on the bus

ret = dbus_bus_request_name(connection, WPAS_DBUS_SERVICE, 0, &error);
if (dbus_error_is_set(&error))
{
printf(stderr, "Name Error (%s)\n", error.message);
dbus_error_free(&error);
}

/* Connect to signal */
// Interface signal ..
printf(signalDesc, "type='signal',interface='%s'",WPAS_DBUS_IFACE_INTERFACE);
dbus_bus_add_match(connection, signalDesc, &error);
dbus_connection_flush(connection);
if (dbus_error_is_set(&error))
{
fprintf(stderr, "Match Error (%s)\n", error.message);
return 1;
}

// Do main loop
loop(connection);
dbus_connection_close(connection);

return 0;

}
```

## List of D-bus services on my BBB

[image]

## Output

[image]

## Some pointers

1. I would like to catch the signals as shown in the [D-Bus API](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/dbus.html) of wpa_supplicant.
2. Some things I would like to do -- see when a wireless interface say `wlan0` is enabled, connects to access point etc. Also capability to set AP and stuff.
3. Its catching signal from other interfaces for which no match has been added.
4. I run this program and change the state of the networking interfaces but I dont get any signals. Also, I dont know if requesting name on the bus is necessary as I'm just listening.

What's the possible issue here? Any pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: Did you check if there are any signals sent by wpa_supplicant at all? You could check with dbus-monitor. You could also check if your add_match calls are correct that way.